# access token request with box api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, box-api, rest-client

I have a problem sending the access token request with box api and the rest client gem :

**request**

```
access_token_params = {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: params[:code],
      client_id: box_params[:client_id],
      client_secret: box_params[:client_secret]
    }

    RestClient.post('https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/token', params: access_token_params){ |response, request, result, &block|
      check_request_success(response, "send_access_token")
    }
```

with:

```
def box_params
    {
      client_id: "my_id",
      client_secret: "my_secret"
    }
  end
```

**error:**

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

Comment: Box isn't clear on this either, but double-check your URL endpoints. `https://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2` specifies `https://api.box.com` while `https://developers.box.com/oauth/` states that the endpoint is `https://app.box.com`. Try switching to api.box and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

### First

Your `RestClient.post()` function incorrect. Because it is a `post` you should not have `params:` hash but rather the payload itself. This is because post requests don't have params in the url, but rather in a payload in the body of the request.

### Second

[The Box API Docs](https://developers.box.com/docs/) & [Oauth Tutorial page](https://developers.box.com/oauth/) reference two endpoints. The correct endpoint for the request on the API docs: `https://api.box.com/oauth2/token`

Try this:

```
  RestClient.post('https://api.box.com/oauth2/token', access_token_params ){ |response, request, result, &block|

            check_request_success(response, "send_access_token")   
    }
```